# Error setwd() "cannot change working directory"

Tags: r, working-directory, setwd

I get "cannot change working directory" error when I try to set up my working directory:

```
setwd("C:\Users\alimo\Desktop\DataVisualizationwithggplot2.R")
```

> ```
> *Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"*
> ```

then I ran:

```
options(PACKAGE_MAINFOLDER="C:/Users/...")
```

and replaced all "" to "/" but I got this error this time:

> ```
> cannot change working directory
> ```

Comment: Either `setwd("C:\\Users\\alimo\\Desktop\\DataVisualizationwithggplot2.R")` or `setwd("C:/Users/alimo/Desktop/DataVisualizationwithggplot2.R")`

Comment: But you cannot change directory to an R file, consider `setwd("C:/Users/alimo/Desktop")`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, writing a path to a file or directory can sometimes be a bit painful, especially when you move across different platforms!

[`setwd()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html) sets the working directory, so it means you need to specify a directory, not a file.

And whenever I'm not sure about the single/double (back)slashes, I like to use [`file.path()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html) from base R, which adds a correct delimiter in a platform-independent way:

```
file.path("~", "myfolder", "myfile.R")
```

So for your case:

```
setwd(file.path("C:", "Users", "alimo", "Desktop"))
```

Comment: (1) double-backslashes are only required if the user chooses to use backslashes; on Windows, R will accept either, so there really is no need to *type in* backslashes (though other commands/env-vars will still contain backslashes). (2) Good use of `file.path`, further good to know is that it has an argument `fsep=` which defaults to `\\` on windows and `/` everywhere else. When I use `file.path`, even on windows I almost always use `fsep="/"` since backslashes hurt my eyes. **However**, once can *always* get the file-sep with `.Platform$file.sep` (default value for `file.path`, btw).